# Proxy IP Address Through Nginx Varnish Apache For WHMCS

Tags: php, apache, nginx, proxy, varnish

After successfully configuring the setup on Ubuntu12.04.5 [Visitor>Nginx>SSL Termination>Varnish3.0>Apache], I installed WHMCS and encountered an error, "The page isn't redirecting properly".

After [searching online](http://forum.mratwork.com/kloxo-mr-tips-and-tricks/php-force-redirect-ssl-nginxproxy-endless-loop/) I followed those steps..

So I added following line in my concerned server block:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
```

And then I added following line in my .htaccess file:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== on) {

SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Protocol https HTTPS=on
```

It went well, stopped redirecting and I could access my admin panel over https.

Now while logging into WHMCS admin panel, I found that the IP tracking in WHMCS shows that visitor IP is 127.0.0.1 on the login page. Even though I have added following lines to my nginx server block:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Yet it seems the IP is not getting passed on and WHMCS is picking the proxy 127.0.0.1 coming from port 80 through varnish.

Can someone please advice how to configure server so that real IP is passed on & understood by Apache/WHMCS?

PS: I have tried but failed to implement [Real IP Module](http://http//nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html)

My nginx server block is shown below:

---

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

---

Also, I checked PHP Info into my WMCS and found the following:

**Apache Environment**

HTTP_X_REAL_IP - shows my CloudFlare DNS IP

HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP - shows my real IP

HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR - shows three IPs namely, my real IP, my CloudFlare DNS IP, 127.0.0.1

Maybe this could help to investigate the matter..

--

### SV

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution while using WHMCS with cloudflare protection .. I've tried many solutions .. Never worked ..

I really want to thank Saurabh Vashist for sharing that solution .. After little editing on WHMCS Configuration file to put in :

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']) && 
$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] != '') {
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
} else {
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

The real Visitor IP's now appears again ..

Thank you very much for sharing guys ..

Answer (score 0):

After searching left & right, ultimately landed answers from [WHMCS Support](http://docs.whmcs.com/Security_Tab#Trusted_Proxy_Settings) & [CloudFlare Module](https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads#mod_cloudflare).

Although my CloudFlare module is still not working but temporarily I have been able to resolve the Real IP issue by adding all CloudFlare IPs to trusted proxy list in WHMCS security settings.

Still got no idea why mod_cloudflare is not able to supply correct IP to the Apache server :(

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your configuration.php:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] != '') {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Or try:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] != '') {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
} else {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```